# Handling save password promt in chrome using selenium

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, authentication

Could anyone please let me know how to disable save password prompt in google chrome using selenium with java,i just updated my driver to 2.29 version.I am using windows 10 and chrome version is 57.0.2987.133.Please note that i am using selenium 3.0.1.Also ,I have gone through many posts in google but nothing seems to be working.Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry i am not using windows 10..its windows 7

Comment: Try uisng Incognito mode

Answer (score 0):

try below:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
options.addArguments("--disable-web-security");
options.addArguments("--no-proxy-server");
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", false);
prefs.put("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
```

Comment: did this Solution work for you? I tried out this option but it didn't work for me.

Comment: @Dev : Please try with my updated answer ,I've found something at  https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/26275/how-to-disable-chrome-save-your-password-selenium-java

Comment: This works with one of the typical kind of password manager, but then there is one more kind of password bubble which I am still unable to handle. The one you mentioned I always use that in my code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Invoke Chrome in this way.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","path to chromedriver.exe");
     ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
     options.addArguments("--incognito");
     DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
     capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
     WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```